# Using multiple OS's on a UEFI secure boot system

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, windows-8.1, operating-systems, uefi

I wanted to install Ubuntu on a windows 8.1 system but I don't want to use GRUB or replace my current boot loader. Can I install multiple OS's without showing a prompt to select An OS unless I press a specific button at boot time?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think to what you describe would be something like having Ubuntu on a USB drive and having the internal hard drive take precedence in the boot order.  It would boot normally unless you hit the key (typically F12 or Esc) at startup to select the boot device, in which case, you could select the drive containing Ubuntu.